# How to change value of another form using different form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two from f1 and f2. When f2 is loaded i use this code:

```
f2 emp = new f2();
emp.MdiParent = f1;
emp.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
emp.Show();
```

f1 has a public variable

```
public string name;
```

I want to access the f1.name via f2.
How can I do that?

Comment: `string form1EmpName = emp.name;` or `emp.name = "John Doe";` - By the way, having public fields is considered bad practice.  Use properties instead (`public string Name { get; set; }`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see no `f2` in your example. Usually I do something like this:

Create an interface that describes what `f1` does:

```
interface if1
{
    string Name {get;}
}
```

Implement this in `f1`:

```
public class f1 : Form, if1
{
    public string Name { get { return name; } }
}
```

Pass `f1` to `f2`:

```
f1 emp = new f1();
f2 x = new f2(f1);
```

Constructor of `f2`:

```
public f2(if1 f1)
{
    string nameOfForm1 = f1.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

f1 with the Attribute "name":

```
public class f1 : Form
{
    public string name;
}
```

f2:

```
public class f2 : Form
{
    public f2(f1 form)
    {
        string name = form.name;
    }
}
```

And create them like this:

```
f1 form = new f1();
f2 emp = new f2(form);
```